# Как вывести без сортировки?

Tags: sql, oracle

**Пытаюсь вывести значения именно в том порядке, в котором они указаны в select запросах, но выводится в порядке возрастания**

```
create table cities(name varchar2(100));
insert into cities(name) values('Москва   ');
insert into cities(name) values('Москва');
insert into cities(name) values('Москва ');
insert into cities(name) values('Тверь    ');
insert into cities(name) values('Тверь     ');
insert into cities(name) values('Севастополь  ');
select length(name)-length(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(name,'а',''),'е',''),'ё',''),'и',''),'о' ,''), 'у',''),'ы',''), 'э', ''),'ю', ''), 'я', '')) from cities where replace(name, ' ', '')='Москва'
union 
select min(length(name)-length(REPLACE(name, ' ', ''))) from cities where replace(name, ' ', '')='Москва'
union 
select max(length(name)-length(REPLACE(name, ' ', ''))) from cities where replace(name, ' ', '')='Москва'
```

Пользуюсь Oracle Sql Developer
Выводит в порядке 0,2,3, а мне необходимо вывести без костылей по типу псевдостолбцов в порядке, в котором я создаю запросы select

Comment: Заменить UNION на UNION ALL.

Comment: Заменял. в итоге всё равно ничего не выходит

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0b96cd68d31fe899834eca4b1a0cf313

Comment: мне нужно именно 3 числа именно в порядке 2 0 3

Comment: Я так подозреваю, что без явной сортировки порядок вывода не регламентирован. Движок базы данных может оптимизировать запросы так, как ему захочется.

Comment: тогда без костыля-псевдостолбца не обойтись?

Comment: Ну, я не настоящий ораклист, но подозреваю что да, лучше добавить в вывод какое-то поле, по которому можно будет отсортировать. Но вообще странно называть разные сущности одной колонкой. Тут скорее надо наоборот в разных колонках по-разному считающиеся штуки выводить, а не в одну колонку всё подряд. И тогда всё будет понятно где что. А полагаться на порядок вывода - дело ненадёжное.

Comment: Вот тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552019/how-to-execute-union-without-sorting-sql есть какие-то советы, но, мне кажется, проще сделать сортировку доп. полю ))

Comment: мне показалось более сложным создать отдельную таблицу с вычисляемыми значениями, поскольку пришлось бы дописывать триггер-функцию для того. чтобы проделывать операции со значениями из других таблиц

Comment: Мне кажется, у вас вообще "проблема XY", вы зачем это хотите вообще сделать? Вы явно решаете задачу, которую наверняка не нужно решать вообще.

Comment: Дана таблица с городами, которые написаны с несколькими пробелами в конце. Для каждого города посчитать:
- количество гласных букв в написании города
- минимальное количество пробелов
- максимальное количество пробелов
Упорядочить названия городов в алфавитном порядке.
Должно получиться
Москва 2 0 3
Севастополь 4 2 2
Тверь 1 4 5

Comment: А, ну вот. Я же говорю - эти цифры просто должны быть в разных колонках, зачем вы их собираете в одну колонку? А сортировка будет по колонке с названием города. Всё понятно.